# Why do my slimes keep teleporting out of their hutches?

Tags: stardew-valley

I have ten Slime Hutches, almost all of them housing 20 slimes each, but for some reason every now and then I'll find a slime behind one of my hutches (always the same one), or even outside of the farm bounds. What's up with that? Is it a bug? Feature? Can I prevent it from happening?

[image: Get down here!]

Comment: I think you may have too many slimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I think I know what causes it. Sometimes a slime will glitch and get stuck inside the wall of a hutch, and this apparently causes the game to bug and put the slime somewhere else entirely. I recently noticed a pink slime being stuck in its hutch's wall, and later the same day, I found it freely roaming around my farm. When I went back to check in the pink slimes hutch, there was no slime stuck in the wall anymore.

Sadly, there's no way to prevent this from happening, so here's hoping it gets fixed in 1.1.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Animals#Slimes):

> It is also important to note that once the hutch has more than 5 Slimes, there is a 3.5% chance per night per slime to escape and disappear.

I'm guessing that's why you see a loose slime from time to time. As for why they sometimes appear outside the boundaries of the farm, I'd guess that's a legitimate bug (I've seen screenshots of other similar problems, like the player's pet being out of bounds).

Comment: Well, these are clearly not disappearing. No matter which hutch they vanish from, they all appear behind the first hutch I built, which is right below the screenshot I posted. Is this "escaping" behaviour intended?

Comment: I'm guessing the wiki wording should be "escape and/or disappear." I believe the escaping behavior is indeed intended, and I don't think there's anything you can do to prevent it. I'm not sure how the game decides where to place escaped slimes.

Comment: I can now safely say this is not intended, and 3.5% is a random number that someone made up for the Wiki.

Comment: Since I finally found the code for this, I'd like to correct my statement. The slime escaping mechanism does indeed happen once you have 5 slimes, and it's correct that each slime has a 3.5% chance to escape, but that only happens to slimes that are not in hutches, only ones left outdoors, even if completely fenced in. That'd explain why I've never seen it happen, but now I'm sure that it doesn't apply to hutches.